# Error in eval(model$call$data) : object data1 not found

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following function to run a simulation study. I function is as follows:-

```
simulation<-function(n, method, process, bsd){
  M<-matrix(1:(10*n), nrow=n, ncol=10)
  U<-matrix(data=NA, nrow=5, ncol=1)

  for(i in 1:5)  {

    if(process=='1') {

      for(j in 1:10) {
        M[,j]<-runif(n, min=0, max=5*j)
      }
      epsilon<-rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=bsd)
    }

 y<-1*M[,2]+2.5*M[,6]+0.8*M[,9]+epsilon

 data1<- data.frame("X1"=M[,2], "X2"=M[,6], "X3"=M[,9],"X4"=M[,1],"X5"=M[,3],"X6"=M[,4],"X7"=M[,5],"X8"=M[,7],"X9"=M[,8],"X10"=M[,10])



  subsetb<-lm(y~0+., data=data1)

    if(method=='1'){
      k<-ols_step_best_subset(subsetb)
      U[i,]<-k$predictors[which.max(k$adjr)]
    }


    if(method=='2'){
      k<-ols_step_best_subset(subsetb) 
      U[i,]<-k$predictors[which.min(k$aic)]
    }

  }  

  V<-data.frame("SV"=U[,1]) 


  V$SV <- sapply(V$SV, function(i){i1 <- strsplit(as.character(i), ' ')[[1]];  
  i2 <- i1[order(as.numeric(gsub('\\D+', '', i1)))]; 
  paste(i2, collapse = ' ')})


  return(V)


}
```

Whenever I try executing `system.time(simulation(50, '1', '1', 1))` I get the following error message with the descriptions:-

```
 Error in eval(model$call$data) : object 'data1' not found 
7.
eval(model$call$data) 
6.
eval(model$call$data) 
5.
mod_sel_data(model) 
4.
ols_step_best_subset.default(subsetb) 
3.
ols_step_best_subset(subsetb) 
2.
simulation(50, "1", "1", 1) 
1.
system.time(simulation(50, "1", "1", 1))
```

I have no idea why it is showing `data1` not found. I suppose the problem arises when I call the `lm` function. Could anyone please point out any mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are still issues, try replacing

```r
y <- 1*M[,2] + 2.5*M[,6] + 0.8*M[,9] + epsilon

data1 <- data.frame("X1"=M[,2],
                    "X2"=M[,6], 
                    "X3"=M[,9],
                    "X4"=M[,1],
                    "X5"=M[,3],
                    "X6"=M[,4],
                    "X7"=M[,5],
                    "X8"=M[,7],
                    "X9"=M[,8],
                    "X10"=M[,10])
```

with

```r
y <<- 1*M[,2] + 2.5*M[,6] + 0.8*M[,9] + epsilon

data1 <<- data.frame("X1"=M[,2],
                     "X2"=M[,6], 
                     "X3"=M[,9],
                     "X4"=M[,1],
                     "X5"=M[,3],
                     "X6"=M[,4],
                     "X7"=M[,5],
                     "X8"=M[,7],
                     "X9"=M[,8],
                     "X10"=M[,10])
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `ols_step_best_subset(subsetb)` by `olsrr::ols_step_best_subset(subsetb)` in every place.

Comment: Yes this time it is working.Thank you for your answer.